# Is there a site to see addresses by zoning laws?

Tags: new-home, rental

I would like to search homes and see properties by zoning laws. For example I am looking for a house but would like to have it also as an airbnb or be able to build another unit in the back to be a rental property etc. Would like to be able to type in an address and see what the zoning laws are for that property etc. Is there a database out there with this information?

Comment: Zoning laws can change and are quite site specific.

Comment: To see how they can change.  Years ago someone wanted to raise pet skunks.  Talked with the government department about his plans and best ways to do it for three years.  Day after he he opened, the government banned all pet skunk places.  After a few years he did win his lawsuit.

Comment: There is not a one-stop shop for this information.

Answer (score 1):

(This answer assumes the poster is in the US)

Start with the website of the county you are looking in.  Look for parcel search or parcel map.  This should at least point you in the right direction.  If there are separate websites for departments, start your search at the tax assessor's office or building/planning office.

Some counties provide all the information you need in a nice easy way, and others provide only some or none - it really depends on the local government and how well they operate.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a zoning map for your county if in the US and the county does zoning (not all do).

If not, the county may be governed by a Master Plan that defines land uses or by different types of ordinances according to use.